# Error in compare array elements with a predefined value?

Tags: ios, xcode, arrays

This is something wired happening in my program, hope you can help me
I m trying to compare array elements inside a if condition, This works when comparing value is zero.

```
if((y[5]<0) && (y[4]>0)){
//do something
}
```

But when i try to compare the value with 20, it fails, if condition is not working!

```
if((y[5]<20) && (y[4]>20)){
    //do something
    }
```

Since my array contains floating numbers, i tried this too, but it too fails,if condition is not working!

```
if((y[5]<20.00f) && (y[4]>20.00f)){
        //do something
        }
```

Any idea why this happens? It drives me crazy! :( :( :(

Comment: can you post the content of y? Btw: you should remove the nsarray tag because you are not using a NSArray

Comment: Can you try printing the value of the array, so we can know that it is correct? NSLog is what you need and since you are using a float I believe %f should be required: NSLog(@"%f",y[5]);

Comment: Array contains data from accelerometer of the ipod, This is a dynamic array, so i need to compare the elements and increment a counter if correct, I have created a global array and assessed it using float *y=[[Shared sharedInstance] input]; .This condition works for zero comparison but not to any numbers, like 20? Why is that?

Comment: You could also try this (float)y[5]<20 and see if this works

Comment: @Lefteris - I tried it too, No problem with it, Even i see that accelerometer values satisfying this condition-> y[5]<20.00f && (y[4]>20.00f . But it's not comparing and updating inside the if, Why?

Comment: @Lefteris - No it's not working bro! :(

Comment: @Lefteris Seems like problem is with the comparison of the elements, Because even this does not work.. if(y[5]<20) and even this if((float)y[5]<20), No idea . Any thought?

Comment: @Francesco Seems like problem is with the comparison of the elements, Because even this does not work.. if(y[5]<20) and even this if((float)y[5]<20), No idea . Any thought?

Comment: @sam try printing the y[5] and y[4] before the if...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try :

```
  if(([[y objectAtIndex:5] intValue]<20) && ([[y objectAtIndex:5] intValue]>20))
  {
    //do something
  }
```

Comment: Hey bro, i have no problem with the zero comparison, Array contains data from accelerometer of the ipod, This is a dynamic array, so i need to compare the elements and increment a counter if correct, I have created a global array and assessed it using float *y=[[Shared sharedInstance] input]; .This condition works for zero comparison but not to any numbers, like 20? Why is that?

Comment: Hi, NSArray and NSMutableArray contains objects. I am not sure why it work with zero comparison, but if you need to compare with array objects, you need to get the object and cast that to int/float/double to compare with any number.